# How to make a connection to a database using DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

So I want to have a DDL (SELECT name FROM sys.databases (nolock)) that returns a value once selected (displayed in gridview possibly).

The problem that I have is that the query needs to make a connection to different databases depending on what the user selects from the DDL and return a value that is displayed in gridview.  I want something  like the below query:

How could I accomplish this?

```
use ([name]=@name) select sum(t.table1.column1) as Total from database inner join database2 on db1.table1.id= ([name]=@name).table2.id where([appname]=@appname) and Date <= GetDate()AND YEAR(Date) = year(GetDate())
```

I got this so far (not sure if this is the best method.)  This is my code behind, how do I display the result using gridview that is dependent on DDL?

```
    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "test1")
        {
            SqlDataSource3.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            {
                SqlDataSource3.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
                SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "select top 10 * from table1 (nolock)";
            }
        }

        else if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "test2")
        {
            SqlDataSource4.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            {
                SqlDataSource4.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
                SqlDataSource4.SelectCommand = "select top 1 * from table1 (nolock)";
            }
        }
```

And below is my aspx code for the DDL.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
             <asp:ListItem>test1</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>test2</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to run different SQL when a user selects an item from the DropDownList. Anyway, you should put your code in the SelectedIndexChanged event of the control. As an example, your markup might look something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And in your code-behind:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // call your sql
 }
```

**Edit**

I've included a links to get your started. They show some code with the SelectedIndexChanged event.

http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1294.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/092589/working-with-dropdownlist-slectedindexchanged-event/

Comment: Yes, this sounds like what I want to do.  I'll research on how to properly call the sql query with all the parameters in place.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if it solves your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Its something that I can work on, but i'm bot a programmer/dev.  I'll have to research this to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Added some links with some examples. Good luck.